# how to connect via WebSocket running on Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, nodejs-server

Im have hetzner server on which im trying to run WebSocket. Unfortunately I got stack so here is my code from `test.js`)

```html
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const ws = require('ws');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
};

let server = http.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
});

server.addListener('upgrade', (req, res, head) => console.log('UPGRADE:', req.url));
server.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
server.listen(8080, () => console.log('started on 8080'));

const wss = new ws.Server({ server, path: '/echo' });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('client connected');
    ws.send('Hello');
    ws.on('message', (data) => ws.send('Receive: ' + data));
});
wss.on('error', (e) => console.log(e));
```

* I got this code from some sources

After running the server I got message in console `started on 8080`. Nothing else... I tried to test it but I always got errors with no code. It looks like service where I tested it cannot find WebSocket. It is possible that problem actually in connecting to the serer.

Im  not shure which path string should I use. I have hostname `ubuntu-s****` and server IP `49.****`. I did lots of attempts with `'wss://ubuntu-s***:8080/echo'` and `'wss://49.***:8080/echo'` but none of them gave any result

I still have no messages in console that cliend tried to connect :( Moreover I tried to run it on the local server (of course I removed SSL sertificates connecthion and changed server protocol to HTTP) and it works perfectly!!!

Thanks a lot for urs replies

UPD: message I got when trying to connect ws `WebSocket connection to 'ws://49.***:8080/echo' failed:`

Answer (score 1):

First double check if the IP address is correct then change protocol to HTTP because you are using it on top of HTTP:

`http://49.***:8080/echo`